# How to create two barplots with different x and y axis in tha same plot in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart, axis-labels

I need plot two grouped barcodes with two dataframes that has distinct number of rows: 6, 5.

I tried many codes in R but I don't know how to fix it

Here are my data frames: The Freq colum must be in Y axis and the inter and intra columns must be the x axis.

```
> freqinter
              inter Freq
1 0.293040975264367   17
2 0.296736775990729    2
3 0.297619926364764    4
4 0.587377012109561    1
5 0.595245125315916    4
6 0.597022018595893    2

> freqintra
              intra Freq
1                 0    3
2 0.293040975264367   15
3 0.597022018595893    4
4 0.598809552335782    2
5 0.898227748764939    6
```

I expect to plot the barplots in the same plot and could differ inter e intra values by colour

I want a picture like this one:
[image: graph]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the data you posted I don't think you can have this graph to look good. You can't have bars thin enough to differentiate  `0.293` and `0.296` when your data ranges from `0` to `0.9`.

Maybe you could try to treat it as a factor just to illustrate what you want to do:

```
freqinter <- data.frame(x = c(
0.293040975264367,
0.296736775990729,  
0.297619926364764,
0.587377012109561,   
0.595245125315916,   
0.597022018595893), Freq = c(17,2,4,1,4,2))

freqintra <- data.frame(x = c(
               0 ,
0.293040975264367,
0.597022018595893,
0.598809552335782,
0.898227748764939), Freq = c(3,15,4,2,6))

df <- bind_rows(freqinter, freqintra, .id = "id")

ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(x), y = Freq, fill = id)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single")) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
      scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("inter", "intra"))
```

[image]

You can also check the problem by not treating your `x` variable as a factor:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = Freq, fill = id)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.05, position = "dodge") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("inter", "intra"))
```

Either the bars must be very thin (small `width`), or you'll get overlapping `x` intervals breaking the plot.

[image]

Comment: It’s exactly what I want in graph one Freguglia. Is that way to fix the x axis for example 0 to 0.8 ? Just for fitness and beauty, and color with black and gray.Thanks a lot, I don’t have any idea to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by fix the `x`-axis. You can always change the labels by adding another layer like `+ scale_x_discrete(labels = c(0, 0.293, 0.296, 0.297, 0.587, 0.595, 0.597, 0.598, 0.898)` and define how you want it to look like. The problem with the scale is that you're treating `x` as a factor, therefore, there is no notion of distance in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot... my idea was to reduce the size of the numbers in x axis. Just to fit better

Comment: I know OP said bar graph, but the plot he is showing is actually a histrogram.

Comment: The data already consists of (probably binned) counts, building a histogram is essentially the same as a bar plot (possibly combining `x` values) if you just replicate the data.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a histogram. Use the raw data if possible. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

freqinter <- data.frame(x = c(
  0.293040975264367,
  0.296736775990729,  
  0.297619926364764,
  0.587377012109561,   
  0.595245125315916,   
  0.597022018595893), Freq = c(17,2,4,1,4,2))

freqintra <- data.frame(x = c(
  0 ,
  0.293040975264367,
  0.597022018595893,
  0.598809552335782,
  0.898227748764939), Freq = c(3,15,4,2,6))

df <- bind_rows(freqinter, freqintra, .id = "id") %>% 
  uncount(Freq)

ggplot(df, aes(x, fill = id)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, position = 'dodge', col = 1) +
  scale_fill_grey() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: I need all data plotted... but here some were concatenated isn’t?